# If $f \geq 0$ is continuous and $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx = 0$, then $f =0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Just wanted to confirm that this is a correct solution:

**Proof:**
Suppose $f(x_0) > 0$ for some $x_0 \in [a,b]$. Then, by continuity of $f$, for $\epsilon < f(x_0)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ so that, if $|x-x_0| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. That is to say, $f(x)$ is non-zero in a neighborhood $B_\delta (x_0)$. Now,

\begin{eqnarray*}
U(f,P) &=& \sum_{P([a,b])} M_i \Delta_i \\
&=& \sum_{P(B_\delta(x_0))} M_i \Delta_i \\
&=& \sup_{x \in [x_0-\delta, c_1]} |f(x)| (c_1-(x_0 - \delta)) + \sup_{x \in [c_1,c_2]} |f(x)| (c_2-c_1) + \cdots + \sup_{x \in [c_n, x_0 + \delta]} |f(x)| ((x_0+\delta)- c_n) \\
&>& 0
\end{eqnarray*}

In the same manner,

\begin{eqnarray*}
L(f,P) &=& \sum_{P([a,b])} m_i \Delta_i \\
&=& \sum_{P(B_\delta(x_0))} m_i \Delta_i \\
&=& \inf_{x \in [x_0-\delta, c_1]} |f(x)| (c_1-(x_0 - \delta)) + \inf_{x \in [c_1,c_2]} |f(x)| (c_2-c_1) + \cdots + \inf_{x \in [c_n, x_0 + \delta]} |f(x)| ((x_0+\delta)- c_n) \\
&\geq& 0
\end{eqnarray*}

We can conclude from here that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx > 0$.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the fact that $$\int_a^b f(x)dx \geq \int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f(x)dx$$ which you can make strictly positive

Answer (score 1):

It's sufficient to consider the inferior sum. Also, you should specify which partition is $P$ (I will denote it by $P_0$): It should be a partition such that one of the subintervals determined by $P_0$ is contained in $B_\delta (x_0)$, in this way, if this interval is $I$, your argument should be

$$
L(f,P_0) = \sum_{P_0([a,b])} m_i \Delta_i 
\geq \inf_{x \in I} |f(x)| \mathcal{V}(I)>0  $$

(here we used the fact that $f\geq 0$) and therefore

$$\int_a^b f(x)=\sup_{P}L(f,P)\geq L(f,P_0)>0$$

(Notice that you must put a more restricted condition to $\epsilon$ in order to conclude $\inf_{x \in I} |f(x)| \mathcal{V}(I)>0$)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, fix $t \in (a,b)$. $0 \le \int_a^t f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(x) I(x \le t) dx \le \int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$ so that $\int_a^t f(x) dx = 0$.

Using the continuity of $f$ we can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to get $f(t) = 0$ for $t \in [a,b]$