# Show that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx>0$.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ with $f(x)\geq 0$ and such that $f(x) > 0$ for some $x\in\mathbb [a,b]$. Show that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx>0$.

Comment: Let $f(x_0)>0$. The integral on $[a,b]$ is $\ge$ the integral on a suitably small neighbourhood of $x_0$. Now...

Comment: And [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223367/if-f-geq-0-is-continuous-and-int-ab-fx-dx-0-then-f-0?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = c > 0$ for some $x$.  Choose $\delta > 0$ so that if $y \in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$ then $f(y) > \frac{c}{2}$.  Then $\int_{a}^b f(y) dy \ge \int_{x - \delta}^{x+\delta} f(y) dy \ge \delta c > 0$